# WordPress warning refers to WooCommerce at top single webpage only

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, warnings

I get the following displayed at the top of this web page...

http://hippiechickoriginals.com/product-category/manifesto-mania/

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'woocommerce_price_filter' not found or invalid function name in /home/hippiech/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 214
>
> Warning: array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/hippiech/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-query.php on line 370

Thank you again for your considerations.

Best regards,
Marc

Comment: Does the issue persist if you use a default theme?

Comment: Can you search this on your project 'woocommerce_price_filter' ? And put here the result.